# "[Warning] extra tokens at end of" while compiling my code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to compile and run this code, but not getting the expected result.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>>

using namespace std;

const double uData = 45;
const double mData = 25;
const double lData = 15;
const double militaryY = 0.10;
const double militaryN = 0.00;

int main ()

{ 

    double uData, mData, lData, subTotal, tAmount, fTotal, ssTotal, pLines;
    char dataType, miitaryY, militaryN


uData = U
mData = M
lData = L
pLines >=1

    if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + uData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + uData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + uData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }
    else if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + mData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + mData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + mData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }
        else if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + lData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + lData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + lData
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal
    }

    cout << "How many phone lines are there(Max 3, **Cannot enter 0**) " << pLines << " ? " << endl;
    cout << "Are you active or retired military (Y or N) " << militaryY << militaryN << " ? " << endl;
    cout << "What type of data plan are you using (U, M, L) " << uData << mData << lData << " ? " << endl;
    cout << "Your subtotal is " << subTotal << " $ . " << endl;


        system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> //3    18  C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp [Warning] extra tokens at end of #include directive
>   //C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp  In function 'int main()':
>   //21    1   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected initializer before 'uData'
>   //32    2   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] 'else' without a previous 'if'
>   //35    3   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'fTotal'
>   //41    3   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'fTotal'
>   //46    3   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'fTotal'
>   //52    3   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'fTotal'
>   //57    3   C:\Users\adamp\Desktop\DevCppFiles\Project 4\Powers4.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'fTotal'

Comment: You forgot a `;`. It says it in the error.

Comment: Single characters can matter when you're writing code, and your code has a whole bunch of typos in it. Please read the errors, look at the corresponding lines, and at least attempt to fix them yourself before asking here. Also, some of your local variables have the same name as global variables, and you have a double as a if statement condition which is valid C++ but probably doesn't do what you intended.

Comment: Not to sound rude myself, but did you read the errors? The messages tell you exactly whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra `>` from header:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> // here
```

Fix the following lines:

```c
int main ()

{ 

    double uData, mData, lData, subTotal, tAmount, fTotal, ssTotal, pLines;
    char dataType, miitaryY, militaryN; // add ; here


uData = U; // add ; here 
mData = M; // add ; here
lData = L; // add ; here
pLines >=1???? // Don't know what are you trying to do.

if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + uData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + uData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + uData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
    else if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + mData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + mData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + mData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
        else if (militaryY)
    {
        ssTotal = (pLines + lData) * militaryY;
        subTotal = ssTotal + pLines + lData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
    else if (militaryN)
    {
        subTotal = fTotal + pLines + lData; // add ; here
        fTotal = (subTotal * tAmount) + subtotal; // add ; here
    }
```

**Update:**
Possible structure of your code can be:

```c
int main ()
{

  double uData, mData, lData, subTotal, tAmount, fTotal, ssTotal, pLines;
  char dataType, miitaryY, militaryN;

  cin >> pLines;

  for (int i = 0; i < pLines; i++)
    {
        cin >> uData;
        cin >> mData;
        cin >> lData;
        cin >> dataType;

        if (dataType == 'Y')
        {
          // do something here
        }
        else            // dataType == 'N'
        {
          // do something here           
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Last night I kept trying to fix the errors and thought I had, done exactly what it said. Still kept getting them. The first error was giving me the most trouble. I am brand new to this and still learning. Thank you so much Kamol.

Comment: @AdamPowers Accept the answer if it was helpful. :D

Comment: After I went through and fixed everything I still cannot get it to allow me to enter in data...This project I am working on for school, I need the user to enter how many phone lines, military (Y or N) and what data plan..when I run this code it just completes.. am I missing cin?